# Rebuild android project caused to errors in build fileUnableToDeleteFileException

Tags: android, android-studio

when I try to sync project with gradle file an error occurred with a text:

> Project `SDK` is not defined.

Now, after setting `JDK` and `SDk` when I try to rebuild the project, it's showing the error:

> org.gradle.api.file.UnableToDeleteFileException: Unable to delete directory

Then its again prompting to setup `SDK`.

I have already tried updating `JAVA_HOME` variable, configuring `android studio's` default project structure, but nothing worked

Just a question: When a project is rebuild, does the build file under app folder gets deleted and created again?

Comment: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck this Check box (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Comment: instant run option is not showing. I am using 3.5.2 version.

Comment: In android studio 3.5 instant Run is remove. If you have a problem in app installation multiple time Then go to => run Configuration => Installation Option ==> Default apk ==> install flag ==> -r -t ==>Apply ==> Run Then your problem solve of instant run

Answer (score 0):

Try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.
This solution worked for me.

Comment: Actually the problem was in the JDK version installed. Reinstallation of JDK of another version works for me. Thanks anyway.